# How can I activate a Python virtual environment and launch a python script, in a bash script on Mac?

Tags: python, bash, macos

I am trying to create a bash script that will simply

1. Activate my venv
2. Launch a python script

that can be double clicked and executed on Mac.

My script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./macVenv/bin/activate
python main.py
```

I can run from command line just fine.  When I double click though it complains it cannot find the python file.

Comment: You aren't sourcing the file; you're trying to execute it. `. ./macVenv/bin/activate` (assuming you run the script from the directory containing `macVenv`).

Comment: You can add the entire path or the relative path to the main.py file

Comment: So i made the change to use `source` in front of the activate command and used the entire path to both the main.py and activate command.  What is odd is there is an `os.getcwd()` call within that main.py file, and when I double click my script, that call is not returning the directory where the main.py file is located.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The following script works on my machine.

```
source activate $1
python $2
```

I run it by typing ./script_name py36 python_file_name

where script_name is the name of the script with these 2 lines. py36 is the name of the virtual environment and python_file_name is the python script you want to run.

Comment: For me I get an error on "activate" saying "No such file or directory".  Also my goal is to be able to just "double click" this file, not execute from command line.

Comment: For example, on Windows I have a simple .bat file that just has `venv\Scripts\activate.bat & python main.py`   this way if i run command line or double click, it runs my app just fine.  What's the best way to do that on Mac

Comment: Well, you still need to input the name of the file and the name of the environment you want to activate.

Answer (score 0):

I used to activate .venv

```
cd .venv/bin
source activate
```